# What's difference between "*variable" and "*variable[]" in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have two different versions of codes using char array in C programming language.

First version:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

Second version:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

All codes compiling without warnings or errors, so there's any difference between this codes?

Comment: In the case of the `main()` function, the first is correct and the second is incorrect. (See [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c) which also covers the arguments passed in as well as the return type).  The difference is between pointer to some pointers to characters (first case) and a pointer to some characters (second case).  Note that some compilers will complain (correctly) about the second case — that isn't a legitimate signature for `main()`.

Comment: second code section was wrong.

Comment: I recommend [this `main` function reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function). And probably a good book or tutorial about pointers and arrays.

Comment: The second should be `char **argv`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208444/c-difference-between-and

Comment: Please double check your question for "typos".

Comment: In the context of defining function parameters this `char *argv[]` is 100% equivalent to `char **argv`. This holds for all types and all levels of indirection. So this `char argv[]` is equivalent to `char *argv`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From C Standard#5.1.2.2.1p1

> 1 The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
>
> ```
>     int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
>     int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;10) or in some other implementation-defined manner.

As per the standards, your second version is incorrect:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling it with `gcc` compiler, I am getting following error message:

`prg.c:1:5: error: second parameter of 'main' (argument array) must be of type 'char **'`

Answer (score -1):

For `main` function, it's better to define the second parameter `argv` as `*argv[]` or `**argv`.

This parameter will have no usage if your program doesn't handle any "command line parameters". But if you need it (for example, the `-lR` string in `ls -lR`), you may notice that the parameter**s** will become a 2-d char array, or we say an array of (parameter) string**s**. Since a "string" in C can be `char*` or `char[]` in different situations, then we can represent a 2-d char array as `char *argv[]` or `char **argv`.

Besides, if you use `gcc -Wall`, the second program will produce a warning, saying the type of second parameter of `main` should be `char**`.

Comment: *Since a "string" in C can be char* or char[] in different situations, then we can represent a 2-d char array as char *argv[] or char **argv*- A string is always an array of `char`, period. You can point to the first character using `char *` too, as an array would decay in almost all contexts. But `char *argv[]` and `char **argv` - the one that changes is *not* the "string" but the "array".