# Is there a better way to fetch this value from "char **"?

Tags: c, pointers, command-line-arguments, implicit-conversion, c-strings

I'm studying C in order to start doing some fun low-level code stuff, and I've stumbled into a scenario which I can't wrap my head around, and I'm sure it's because I don't have a lot of experience with it.

Currently my code is very simple: it takes some arguments, and gets the first parameter passed to `main`, and stores it as a path string. The first question that came to mind, was whether it would be correct to store the `main` params as `char *args[]` or `char **args`, and I decided to go with `char **args` since according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208444/c-difference-between-and) there could be some scenarios where the first would not be accessible, and I just wanted to make a code that would be as complete as possible, and learn the whys on the process.

Here's is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char **args) {
    if (args[1] == NULL) return 1;

    // Get path of input file
    char *path = &*args[1];

    fputs(path, stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

**Given the code above, what would be a better way of fetching the value stored in `*args[1]`?** It seems very cryptic when I look at it, and it took me a while to get to it as well.

My understanding is that `char **args`, is a pointer, to an array of pointers. Thus, if I'm to store a string or any other value for later use in one of the indexes of `args`, I would have to assign a new pointer to a memory location (`*path`), and assign the value of the given index to it (`&*args[i]`). Am I over complicating things? Or is this thought process correct?

Comment: Doesn't `char* path = args[1];` work?

Comment: Unless `argc > 1` this is undefined behaviour. Check before accessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters these two function declarations

```
int main(int argc, char **args)
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char *args[])
```

are fully equivalent because the compiler adjusts the parameter that has an array type to pointer to the array element type.

In the initializer expression of this declaration

```
char *path = &*args[1];
```

applying the two operators `&` and `*` sequentially is redundant. So you may just write

```
char *path = args[1];
```

Also in general instead of the condition in the if statement

```
if ( args[1] == NULL) return 1;
```

it will be more safer to write

```
if ( argc < 2 ) return 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write:

```
char *path = args[1];
```

`&` and `*` operators are inverses of each other, so `&*` or `*&` can simply be removed from an expression.